# Android Login Register: Cant insert data into a database using volley

Tags: java, android, phpmyadmin, android-volley, registration

guys im stucking in a hard place. With volley i try to create users in the database on 000webhost. Therefore i use this Register.php

```html
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id6777294_l2w", "123l2w456", "id6777294_l2w");
    
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["grade"])){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $class = $_POST["grade"];
}

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO user(name, email, password, grade) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssi", $name, $email, $password, $grade);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  
    
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

and the following two android classes

```html
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText nameID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameID);
        final EditText emailID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailID);
        final EditText passwordID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordID);
        final EditText gradeID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gradeID);
        final Button registerbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);

        registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //we need to get the data given by the user
                final String name = nameID.getText().toString();
                final String email = emailID.getText().toString();
                final String password = passwordID.getText().toString();
                final int grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeID.getText().toString());

                //now we need a String Listener for the constructor
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    /**
                     * everything in here happens when the response listener has been executed,
                     * given the response (which comes as a JSON String) from the Register.php.
                     * If the response is not in the form of a JSON format, then JSONException
                     * will catch the error
                     */

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            //if successful then go back to LoginActivity, if not make an alert
                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Registrierung fehlgeschlagen").setNegativeButton("Wiederhole",null).create().show();

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };

                //this actual creates the request we need for registration
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, email, password, grade, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

```html
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText nameID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameID);
        final EditText emailID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailID);
        final EditText passwordID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordID);
        final EditText gradeID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gradeID);
        final Button registerbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);

        registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //we need to get the data given by the user
                final String name = nameID.getText().toString();
                final String email = emailID.getText().toString();
                final String password = passwordID.getText().toString();
                final int grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeID.getText().toString());

                //now we need a String Listener for the constructor
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    /**
                     * everything in here happens when the response listener has been executed,
                     * given the response (which comes as a JSON String) from the Register.php.
                     * If the response is not in the form of a JSON format, then JSONException
                     * will catch the error
                     */

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            //if successful then go back to LoginActivity, if not make an alert
                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Registrierung fehlgeschlagen").setNegativeButton("Wiederhole",null).create().show();

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };

                //this actual creates the request we need for registration
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, email, password, grade, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

I get no error or a hint from logcat etc. The time i click on the Register Button i get back to the LoginActivity and it seems perfekt. BUT when checking the database with phpmyadmin there is no new entry in the "user" data.

Please help, i did all suggested improvements and cleared the common mistakes, but it wont store data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your bind parameter statement you're passing in the parameter $grade, but I do not see a $grade variable initialized, did you mean to pass in $class? Might be a start to check that.

Comment: Aww man thx so much, i accidentially uploaded the old php file to 000webhost, therefore i didnt found the mistake